# Cannot run 'Pod Setup'

Tags: ios, macos, cocoapods

CocoaPods returns error when I was trying to `Pod install`. Following are what I tried so far after some Google:

- As mentioned in `http://blog.cocoapods.org/Repairing-Our-Broken-Specs-Repository/`, I have removed and re-downloaded the master repo with `sudo rm -fr ~/.cocoapods/repos/master/` and `Pod Setup`
- Reinstall CocoaPods and xcodeproj from gem
- Install with CocoaPods 0.36.0 beta

I am using Xcode 6.1.1 and Yosemite 10.10.2.

```
$ pod setup --verbose

Setting up CocoaPods master repo

Creating shallow clone of spec repo `master` from `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` (branch `master`)
$ /usr/local/bin/git clone 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' master --depth=1
Cloning into 'master'...
Checking out files: 100% (26795/26795), done.
$ /usr/local/bin/git checkout master
Already on 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
[!] There was an error reading '/Users/sythus/.cocoapods/repos/master/CocoaPods-version.yml'.
Please consult http://blog.cocoapods.org/Repairing-Our-Broken-Specs-Repository/ for more information.

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.35.0/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:316:in `rescue in version_information'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.35.0/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:313:in `version_information'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.35.0/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:234:in `check_version_information'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.35.0/lib/cocoapods/command/repo.rb:57:in `block in run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.35.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:49:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.35.0/lib/cocoapods/command/repo.rb:49:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.35.0/lib/cocoapods/command/setup.rb:84:in `add_master_repo'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.35.0/lib/cocoapods/command/setup.rb:40:in `block in run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.35.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:49:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.35.0/lib/cocoapods/command/setup.rb:32:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.7.0/lib/claide/command.rb:271:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.35.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:45:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.35.0/bin/pod:43:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I missed an issue in CococPods. It seems like the problem comes with psych 2.0.8 [Pod setup error. #2908](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2908)

```
sudo gem uninstall psych
sudo gem install psych -v 2.0.5
```

Comment: Found this great answer after 2hrs of investigating in the wrong direction! Thanks